# How do I add all results from my loop

Tags: java, loops

Question Answered: Thank you everyone for the help!!!

i'm having a bit of trouble with finishing my code mainly because I'm really new to coding, but nonetheless I'm still trying. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I have 3 problems:

- My main problem is that i do not understand how to get my code to add all the totals from each loop.
- Also, after the loop starts it won't end when I enter '0' anymore, but if i end the loop when i first run the loop it will work.
- Finally, how do i make the decimal total to show up in this format; xx.xx rather than xx.xxxxxxx?

Thank you in advance, i really appreciate any help

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class takeOrders {//Find totals and average price 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int euro; // what country the candy canes are from   
        int us;// what country the candy canes are from
        int holder; //place holder for user input of location    
        int v110 = 0; //110v
        int v240 = 0; //240v
        int sum = 0, i = 1;
        double total = 0;
        double discount = 0;

        do {
            //Prompt what country the order is for
            System.out.println("What country is the order for? (press '0' to see the Net Total of order) ");
            System.out.println("1: Europe\n2: U.S.");
            holder = input.nextInt();
            // 110 or 240 voltage 
            if (holder == 1) {
                //How many boxes are ordered EUROPE
                System.out.println("Input number of 240v boxes needed");
                v240 = input.nextInt();
                total = 2.40 * v240;
                System.out.println("Order total: $" + total);
            } else if (holder == 2) {
                // How many boxes are ordered US
                System.out.println("Input number of 110v boxes needed");
                v110 = input.nextInt();
                total = 2.40 * v110;
            }

            // Discount for U.S.  
            if (holder == 2) {
                if (v110 >= 3)
                    discount = total * .05;
            } else if (v110 >= 10) {
                discount = total * .10;
            }
            if (discount > 0) {
                System.out.println("Order total: $" + total);
                System.out.println("Total with Discount: $" + (total - discount));
            }
        } while ((v240 != 0) || (v110 != 0));

    }
}
```

Comment: add more tag to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to finish the loop i would use holder instead of v110 and v240 this way you dont need to enter a country and then an order amount.
The problem can be due to that if you first select US and enter a value this value is retained until you enter again US  an another amount so your loop wonth end unless you select allways the same country and then select 0 as amount

To accumulate total you should do

```
total += 2.40*v240;
```

or

```
total=total+(2.40*v240);
```

This way the total amount will get increased on each loop

In order to format the output you can use this code fragment:

```
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
 System.out.print(df.format(total));
```

I hope this may help you to familiarize with programming and Java.

Answer (score 0):

Once you capture an input, your while condition can never be true, hence the infinite loop.  Instead of

```
while ((v240 != 0) || (v110 != 0));
```

try

```
while (holder != 0);
```

Either that, or you will need to reset v240 and v110 to zero each time you repeat the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using [printf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is the simplest to achieve this.

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", total);
```

So for your case:

```
System.out.printf("Order total: %.2f", total);
```

You can also use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to show up to the digit you want to print.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");           
        System.out.println("Order total:  $" + df.format(total));
```

Comment: I have never used decimalFormat how do i go about starting it? and for the system.out.printf ("%.2f", total);would i just put what i need in the parenthesis and then add the '%.2f?

Comment: I added the printf example in the post. printf is the simplest to use. Going to add the decimanFormat example shortly.

Comment: DecimalFormat added for your case. Please import the Decimal Format library. Please up-vote my answer if that helps.